# Keep the script running even if the user leaves the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

Hi im working in an application let user buy tikcet for some event with nodejs/expressjs/sequelize/react/

When user finish the process of buyin the ticket it would be redirect to a page where will show him the payment was successful and the tickets to donwload

But im worried the user will leave the page before all the tikcets will be prepared than he can't get all the tickets he bought.

The script store the data for each ticket and create ticket on pdf file

For example if he buy 5tickets
And the script will take 2minutes to store data in db and cretae pdf but the user will leave after 1mn here the script will not capable to store all data and create all tickets and this is a problem.

Ho to keep script running even if he leave the page

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When a user buys the tickets, a request is sent from the frontend to the backend node server. The node server is in charge of processing the request and storing the processed data in the database.

If I understand correctly, your concern is that if the user leaves the frontend page, the backend logic processing might be discontinued, but this is actually not the case, the backend logic processing will still continue even if the user has left the frontend page.

Also, another of your concern is that if the user leaves the frontend page, he might not be able to download the prepared pdf, in this situation, you can provide a feature(like a download button in the order history page) in frontend to allow the user to retrieve and download the pdf as many times as he want. Additionally, you can send an email containing info of the bought tickets to the user as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).